Trouble installing NVIDIA 32 bit driver
I can run steam games through the application itself and certain games successfully launch and play like Doki Doki Literature club. However games like Destiny or Poe fail to run and I am met with the response createDXGIFactory1: call failed.
So I did some research and games like that require a 32 bit driver, while I have only the 64 bit driver, I've attempted to download the NVIDIA driver and my terminal presents the following message:
(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or 
"vim -r /home/divinadivine/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-384.111.run"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/home/divinadivin
e/.cache/vim/swap/%home%divinadivine%Downloads%NVIDIA-Linux-x86-384.
111.run.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "~/.cache/vim/swap/%home%divinadivine%Downloads%NVIDIA-Lin
ux-x86-384.111.run.swp" already exists!


What command are you running to produce the error you posted?  Please post the driver you downloaded and the install command you are attempting to use.  Also, what Linux distribution are you running and have you tried to install Nvidia drivers from the distribution repository?

this is part of error message from vim when editing same file in two place.
